# Interactive Map like in Travian

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary

I am making a browser game like travian in our thesis. my difficulties is the map.

I want my map to be interactive such that there will be:
zoom in/out
dragging on the ground makes the map move
grids (not isometric or hex)

all i need to know is how to generate the map. i think i can handle populating it with objects inside such as villages and forest etc. can anybody help me or just provide me a simple example of how to create a map? probably im going to use jquery or html5 right? just a simple example that i can start with. tnx

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a [tutorial](http://www.bhopkins.net/2014/10/08/draggable-zoomable-tile-map-with-pixi-js/) but I don't really understand how the rendering goes. It creates the map like you wanted (and what I wanted too - since I'm making one now). I think that one is perfect, it is using Pixi.js